# How to send message with networkstream (c#)

Tags: c#, networkstream

I want to send messages using networkstream write and read
but I couldn't make it.(I don't know even if message is sent)
I want to know what is the problem and how can I fix the server code.
(I can fix server code only.)

here is server(listener&sender) code

```
    IPAddress ipadd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    Int32 port = 8192;


    private void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipadd, port);
        listener.Start();
    }
    TcpClient tcpClient = null;
    public NetworkStream networkStream = null;
    string ServerIP = "127.0.0.1";
    string ServerPort = "8192";
    private void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        tcpClient.Connect(ServerIP, Convert.ToInt32(ServerPort));

        networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

        byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox3.Text);
        networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
    }
```

and here is client(receiver) code

```
     TcpClient tcpClient = null;
     public NetworkStream networkStream = null;
     string ServerIP = "127.0.0.1";
     string ServerPort = "8192";

     tcpClient = new TcpClient();
     tcpClient.Connect(ServerIP, Convert.ToInt32(ServerPort));

     networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

     FileSizeBytes = new byte[1024];
     ByteSize = networkStream.Read(FileSizeBytes, 0, FileSizeBytes.Length);
     ae = new ASCIIEncoding();
     inputSource = ae.GetString(FileSizeBytes, 0, ByteSize);
```

Comment: Does it just not work or are there errors?

Comment: I think it's not work.

Comment: Okay, have you looked at some examples? Usually you accept a client with `listener.AcceptTcpClient()` instead of creating a new one and connecting it to the Server (only on the server side of course).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will try that.

Comment: Keep in mind that this command will block until it can accept a client.

Comment: Declare your TCPListener outside of the button handler click method - have you followed the example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8